# How to increment inside session in Django?

Tags: django, session, increment

I try to create a counter inside session but I fail. the session is print out the result I added once and it doesn't increment the process when I want to add a new comment again. the comment will be added but counter is still equal to one so, how can I do increment into session:

```
def post(self, request, user_slug, *args, **kwargs):
    my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(ask_slug=user_slug)
    userprof = UserProfile.objects.get(userasking__ask_slug=user_slug)
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    name = "%s %s" % (self.request.user.first_name, self.request.user.last_name)
    username = self.request.user.username
    logo = self.request.user.userprofile.logo.url
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comment_request = self.request.POST.get('comment', None)
        comment_form = Comment.objects.create(comment=comment_request,
                                              userasking_id=my_question.id,
                                              userprofile_id=userprof.id,
                                              name=name,
                                              username=username,
                                              logo=logo,
                                              comment_slug=my_question.ask_slug
                                              )
        q = UserAsking.objects.get(ask_slug=my_question.ask_slug)
        c = comment_form
        u = comment_form.userprofile
        if 'notify_counts' in request.session:
            counter = request.session.get('notify_counts', 0)
            request.session['notify_counts'] = counter + 1
            request.session.save()
            print('%s is commented your post: %s and comment is (%s) notify = %i'
                  %(u, q, c, counter))
        return redirect('community:question_view', user_slug)
        # return redirect('community:question_view', comment_form.userasking.ask_slug)
    return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', {'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, I don't. I just I get the result that increment one time from 0 to become 1, and when I submit a comment every time I get "notify = 1" and that means that counter has been edited to become one after it was 0 but still 1 in every request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically saves to the session database when the session has been modified, so you won't bother to save it manually, take a look：*when session are stored[[Django-Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)*.

```
def post(request，...):
   ...
   notify_counts = request.session.get('notify_counts')
   if notify_counts is None:
       request.session['notify_counts'] = 1
   else:
       request.session['notify_counts'] +=1
```

Also you could use `try...except` pattern as follows：

```
def post(request, ...):
    try:
        request.session['notify_counts'] +=1
    except KeyError:
        request.session['notify_counts'] = 1
```

Comment: I wonder if you have any source that explains how to use session or the source that gives examples for using it instead of Django's document because it's not useful for me at that point?

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin there are many great resources online.  https://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter14.html   https://medium.com/better-programming/managing-sessions-in-django-92ef72db4c63